# Django 'Page not found' error when setting up URLs

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4D3M-NSN58

This is the point where I get the 404 error: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4D3M-NSN58&t=1044s

What I did so far:

Set up a new project,

Created a virtualenv,

Set up views.py,

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def index(response):
    return HttpResponse("<h3>MySite</h3>")
```

Created urls.py inside my ***main*** folder,

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="index"),
]
```

Modified the urls.py inside ***project*** folder

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', include("main.urls")),
]
```

Upon connecting to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ I receive the 404 error.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    home/

The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

I am unable to proceed.

**Solution:**

urls.py inside the ***project*** folder has two paths, one for admin/ and one for home/.

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('home/', include("main.urls")),
    ]
```

Trying to connect to http://127.0.0.1:8000/home or http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin works, but leaving an empty path does not.

This is because if you type /home/ it goes inside the ***main/urls.py*** and looks for a */home/* path. The path is there and it displays what's inside the views.py. In order to display the desired output without entering a path at the end of the URL I had to change the */home/* path to an 'empty' path  inside of the ***project/urls.py***

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("main.urls")),
]
```

Now if no path is entered: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ It will go and look inside the ***main/urls.py*** for an empty path. It will find that an empty path leads to ***project/views.index*** and that is what it displays.

Comment: You're trying to go the root path `/` but your view is tied to the URL pattern `home/`. Try going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home` instead.

Comment: Hierarchical URL patterns in Django are cumulative. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/

Comment: @mario_sunny Thank you, it works. I am wondering why when the person in the tutorial enters the root path, it displays the message for him, instead of the 404.

Comment: It shouldn’t work in the tutorial either. Perhaps they didn’t save after changing `path('', include("main.urls")),` to `path('home/', include("main.urls")),`, so the server was still using the old version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your urls.py

**urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="index"),
]**

and write a view to display message.

Answer (score 0):

as you have put /home in your main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('home/', include("main.urls")),
    ]
```

so you will get a 404 error if you go to localhost:8000/

you have to go to localhost:8000/home to get the index page